# What's the right word for "unclearity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

My dictionary tells me that there is no such word in English. So, what word would you substitute for ***unclearity*** below (please, don't change anything else):

> — There is still something not clear to me in this business. How do they get their profits back if they themselves never come back?
>   — Well, this ***unclearity*** was in fact the very reason why I decided to call this meeting tonight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned "unclarity", which is the word I would use.

Comment: @Colin Fine - Oh boy! It was simply a mere misspelling! I can't believe it! What an anecdote! It's just sooo funny!!! :) :) :)

Comment: This is not a common word.  Most dictionaries appear not to list it, although Merriam-Webster does. Michael Quinion has a [page about the word unclarity](http://www.worldwidewords.org/topicalwords/tw-unc1.htm).

Comment: Indeed, it's not neither in the OED, nor in the OALD. :|

Comment: @mgkrebbs - "*This is not a common word*" - Which looks to me almost like a paradox. Because this one would be the first word that such poor non-native English speaking souls like me would logically arrive at: able → ability, real → reality, certain → certainty, hence, certain → uncertain → uncertainty, clear → unclear → uncl(e)arity - that's how I came up with this "word" in my question after all.

Comment: @brilliant: yes, _unclarity_ is perfectly natural given the root and affixes.  _Clear, clarity,_ and _unclear_ are all common words; nonetheless, _unclarity_ is uncommon (although it would be understood). In fact, the phrase _lack of clarity_ is much more common than the word _unclarity_, as shown in [this interesting historical chart](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=lack+of+clarity%2Cunclarity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  Such is natural language.

Comment: @Alenanno: it is indeed in the OED. Not as a headword, but as a separate entry under "un-", with three citations (two of them being the Webster's entry from 1934 and the quotation from *Smiley's People*, both of them mentioned by Quinion.

Answer (score 9):

You may mean *uncertainty*:

> **uncertainty** |ˌənˈsərtntē|
>   *noun* ( pl. -ties)
>   the state of being uncertain : *times of uncertainty and danger*.
>   • (usu. uncertainties) something that is uncertain or that causes one to feel uncertain : *financial uncertainties*.

Answer (score 9):

You could use **obscurity**, such that:

> Well, this **obscurity** was in fact the very reason why I decided to call this meeting tonight.

Which is defined and exemplified over on [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscurity) as:

> The quality or condition of being imperfectly known or difficult to understand: "writings meant to be understood . . . by all, composed without deliberate obscurity or hidden motives" (National Review).

Or, **ambiguity**, from the [same source as above](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ambiguity):

> Doubtfulness or uncertainty as regards interpretation: "leading a life of alleged moral ambiguity" (Anatole Broyard).

Or, you could use **palpable**, [I guess](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/palpability):

> Easily perceived; obvious

So that the sentence becomes:

> Well, this **lack of palpability** was in fact the very reason why I decided to call this meeting tonight.

But this *does* alter the sentence more than you desire, just an option.

Comment: How about *lack of clarity*?

Comment: @Benjol - I think that one is also good, but I was more after a single word.

Comment: @brilliant Many EL&U questions seek a single word, when really there isn't a single word that a native speaker would use. In many, many cases, the obvious multiple word phrase is the better choice.

Comment: Having said that, there's also *obfuscation*.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "the fact that it was not clearly understandable", then the synonyms can be:

- Unclearness (the best one I guess, derived from "[unclear](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/unclear)");
- [Ambiguity](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/ambiguity) (derived from ambiguous);
- [Incomprehensibility](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/incomprehensibility#incomprehensible) (from incomprehensible);
- Opaqueness (fig., derived from "[opaque](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/opaque)").

Comment: Opacity is another way to say opaqueness.

Answer (score 2):

If Wiktionary is to be believed, then [disclarity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclarity) is a word, albeit an uncommon one.

Answer (score 2):

How about "question?"

This question was the reason....

In fact, the "unclear item" is "how will they get their profits back if they themselves never come back?" and that item is a "question."  The meeting will, presumably, provide an "answer."

Comment: @user7872 - Your suggestion I think is more than acceptable, but it may bear a connotation that the question had been voiced even prior to the idea of calling a meeting, while in my example it could be so that the question was voiced (=articulated=asked) for the first time during the meeting (in other words, the unclarity was there, but nobody dared to look at it (=ask about it)).

Answer (score 1):

[Haziness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/haziness)

Answer (score 1):

For this example, I would use the word "mystery":

> — There is still something not clear to me in this business. How do they get their profits back if they themselves never come back?
>
> — Well, this **mystery** was in fact the very reason why I decided to call this meeting tonight.

While "obscurity" would be a good descriptor for an explanation that fails to satisfy: "Your reasoning is obscure", in this case, there is no explanation mentioned (or implied), so there is nothing to be obscure...it's a mystery (or a phenomenon).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for ***opacity***.

In air or liquid, it's ***turbidity***.

Linguistically, deliberate effort to obscure is ***obliquidy, obliquate***

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obliquity
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turbidity
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obliquate

Comment: You should include a dictionary definition/link for each suggested word.

Comment: Seems a trifle condescending, but, if it's trendy/fashionable in here, I've submitted.  Should I also mention highlighting the word in question, right-clicking and searching?

Answer (score -2):

For another way to describe unclarity I would use **promiscuity**? The Free Dictionary defines it partly as:

> Indiscriminate mingling, mixture, or confusion, as of parts or elements

For example:

> Your answer was a little **promiscuous**, can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: This would not make sense in that position.

Comment: Why couldn't promiscuity be used in that situation?

Comment: No native speaker would describe an answer as promiscuous.

Comment: Is that because promiscuity is often described with people and not situations? The Collins English Dictionary says, "Promiscuous – consisting of a number of dissimilar parts or elements mingled in a confused or indiscriminate manner". Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Your choice of meaning is defined in the OED as archaic and rare. That's all I mean.